# Is there a resource to look up the Standard Industrial Classification codes that companies file with the SEC?

Tags: api, industry

On the NICAR-L mailing list, Matt Kiefer asked:

> Is there a resource to look up the Standard Industrial Classification
>   codes that companies file with the SEC? (They don't use NAICS.)
>
> I need a few hundred so I'm looking for a bulk solution, e.g. an API
>   or a web form that would accept many comma-separated tickers. Not
>   gonna look these up individually on sec.gov.

Comment: What is the point of this question? Why can't the OP ask the question themselves? It seems as though there is a 3rd party dialogue happening here.

Comment: The point? To document useful about SIC data here instead of in the archives of a private mailing list. Is there a problem?

Comment: It seems to me that this just does not follow the type of questions that should be asked here. I'm specifically referring to [what kind of questions shouldn't be asked here](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). The question already *has* an answer, and there is no actual problem to be solved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On the NICAR-L mailing list, Tim Henderson pointed to an HTML listing, at http://www.sec.gov/divisions/corpfin/organization/cfia.shtml

Matt scraped the data and [posted it as a Google document](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AlYUzIaSVEbRdEQ1U1ZOdjRYMVhWU1R5QmhzS194WkE&usp=sharing).

Matt Jacob pointed to another potentially useful resource, [a listing of what the SIC codes actually mean.](http://www.sec.gov/info/edgar/siccodes.htm)

Answer (score 5):

I scraped the SEC data at http://www.sec.gov/divisions/corpfin/organization/cfia.shtml and uploaded it as a [Google Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AlYUzIaSVEbRdEQ1U1ZOdjRYMVhWU1R5QmhzS194WkE#gid=0).

Since that page is dated 2006, it may not be necessary to run the scraper again any time soon, or if the data is updated, the scraper may not work any more, but here is the [python script](https://github.com/mattkiefer/sec-sic-scraper/blob/master/scraper.py) for reference. It requires the BeautifulSoup4 library.